# Change "No chart data available" text to something else

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there any way to change the message "No chart data available" when the chart is not populated?

There are similar questions in stack overflow but even the accepted answer does not solve my problem

```
lineChart.setNoDataText("new text");
```

The above code does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the mistake I made. I was using firebase database in my app. I put the code for line chart inside a value event listener for the database reference. Since this value event listener executes in a separate thread, the setNoDataText is useless. So put the lineChart.setNoDataText("new text") outside value event listener.